# How to detect outliers using DBSCAN?

Tags: data-mining, clustering

I am working on a Fraudulent Cash Transaction Detection System using DBSCAN and I want to know what is the proper way to identify outliers?

Thank you

### ##Edite##

I had a problem how to represent the outer points extracted by the DBSCAN algorithm in Python visualization techniques, and found the solution here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eq1zKgCFwkk

Enjoy your time

Answer (score 1):

There are two parameters to DBSCAN: minPts, and ε.

You have an outlier point if there are fewer than minPts points within ε of it (using the appropriate distance metric). If this isn't the case, it's a sufficiently dense region that there is a cluster here.

Comment: Thanks for your help ^_^